# Elasticsearch lowercase filter search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm trying to search my database and be able to use upper/lower case filter terms but I've noticed while `query`'s apply analyzers, I can't figure out how to apply a lowercase analyzer on a filtered search. Here's the query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "language": "mandarin" // Returns a doc
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "language": "Italian" // Does NOT return a doc, but will if lowercased
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a type `languages` that I have lowercased using:

```
"analyzer": {
    "lower_keyword": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": "lowercase"
    }
}
```

and a corresponding mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "languages": {
        "_id": {
            "path": "languageID"
        },
        "properties": {
            "languageID": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "language": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "lower_keyword"
            },
            "native": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            },
            "meta": {
                "type": "nested"
            },
            "language_suggest": {
                "type": "completion"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have a field that you have analyzed during index to lowercase it, but you are using a term filter for the query which is not analyzed:

> **Term Filter**
>
> Filters documents that have fields that contain a term (not analyzed).
>   Similar to term query, except that it acts as a filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html

I'd try using a query filter instead:

> **Query Filter**
>
> Wraps any query to be used as a filter. Can be placed within queries
>   that accept a filter.

Example:

```
{
    "constantScore" : {
        "filter" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html#query-dsl-query-filter

Comment: So if I wanted tho term to be lowercased would I change the tokenizer to a lowercase one and reindex everything?

Comment: No, it's already lowercased during indexing due to the lowercase filter. The problem is you need to use a query type that will also analyze - Term filters do not.

Comment: Would you see better performance if you just lowercased your input so you could continue using a Term Filter over using a Query Filter?

Answer (score 1):

This may be achieved by appending `.keyword` to your field to query against the keyword version of the field. Assuming language was defined in the mapping with type `keyword`.

Note that now only the exact text would match: `mandarin` won't match and `Italian` would.

Your query would end up like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "language.keyword": "mandarin" // Returns Empty
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "language.keyword": "Italian" // Returns Italian.
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Combining the term values is also allowed:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "language.keyword":
                                     ["mandarin", "Italian"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```