# Computing a new field and aggregating after joining 2 elasticsearch indices

Tags: join, elasticsearch, aggregation

I had posted another question about correlation between 2 elasticsearch indices - [Join elasticsearch indices while matching fields in nested/inner objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518687/join-elasticsearch-indices-while-matching-fields-in-nested-inner-objects). I am now trying to extend on top of that. Following is the code which I created following the answer given for my post.

Data creation:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/currencylookup/inr/1 -d '{
"conv":[
{
"currency":"usd",
"currencyname": "US Dollar",
"units_per_inr":"0.016155969",
"inr_per_unit": "61.89662756" 
},
{
"currency":"inr",
"currencyname": "Indian Rupee",
"units_per_inr":"1",
"inr_per_unit": "1" 
 },

{
"currency":"idr",
"currencyname": "Indonesian Rupiah",
"units_per_inr":"199.2576913",
"inr_per_unit": "0.005018627" 
}
]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/1" -d '{ "amount":"100", "currency":"usd", "location":"USA" }'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/2" -d '{ "amount":"50", "currency":"JPY", "location":"JAPAN" }'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/3" -d '{ "amount":"50", "currency":"inr", "location":"INDIA" }'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/4" -d '{ "amount":"30", "currency" : "IDR", "location": "Indonesia"}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/5" -d '{ "amount":"89", "currency":"USD", "location":"USA" }'
```

Query:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/_search?pretty -d '{
   "query" : {
 "filtered" : {
   "filter" : {
     "terms" : {
       "currency" : {
        "index" : "currencylookup",
         "type" : "inr",
         "id" : "1",
         "path" : "conv.currency"
       },
       "_cache_key" : "currencyexchange"
     }
   }
 }
   }
 }'
```

I get the results - 4 records from expenses index excluding JPY which is not there in currencylookup.

But what I need to do ultimately is to get all expense data in a single currency, so that means I have to do the query other way round, that's when the problem arises.

```
 curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/currencylookup/inr/_search?pretty -d '{
   "query" : {
 "filtered" : {
   "filter" : {
     "terms" : {
         "conv.currency" : {
         "index" : "expenses",
         "type" : "overseas",
         "id" : "2",
         "path" : "currency"
       },
       "_cache_key" : "currencyexchange6"
     }
   }
 }
   }
 }'
```

Looking up against conv.currency does not seem to work. I am not able to specify path for it. I tried to make currencylookup a flat structure, but that also does not work. I don't want to make my expenses as a nested/inner object array.

So, Given an expense id from expenses index, how can I lookup the appropriate currency exchange rate in currencylookup index and compute a new field that has the amount in target currency. eg: for expense id 1, I have to lookup "usd" in currencylookup, get the field inr_per_unit and compute expenseAmountInINR.

And if I get that far I would like to aggregate on the converted expense amount based on some parameters. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the right way to solve this problem, and what I did is a total hack, but what you're asking for can be done using the [scripted metric aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). This aggregation is new in v1.4.x, and is still experimental (so be careful using it in production).

I modified your `currencylookup` index slightly, creating a doc for each conversion factor:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/currencylookup"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/currencylookup/inr/usd" -d'
{
   "currency": "usd",
   "currencyname": "US Dollar",
   "units_per_inr": 0.016155969,
   "inr_per_unit": 61.89662756
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/currencylookup/inr/inr" -d'
{
   "currency": "inr",
   "currencyname": "Indian Rupee",
   "units_per_inr": 1,
   "inr_per_unit": 1
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/currencylookup/inr/idr" -d'
{
   "currency": "idr",
   "currencyname": "Indonesian Rupiah",
   "units_per_inr": 199.2576913,
   "inr_per_unit": 0.005018627
}'
```

and set up the `expenses` index just like you had it:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/expenses"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/1" -d'
{ "amount":100, "currency":"usd", "location":"USA" }'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/2" -d'
{ "amount":50, "currency":"JPY", "location":"JAPAN" }'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/3" -d'
{ "amount":50, "currency":"inr", "location":"INDIA" }'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/4" -d'
{ "amount":30, "currency" : "IDR", "location": "Indonesia"}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/expenses/overseas/5" -d'
{ "amount":89, "currency":"USD", "location":"USA" }'
```

Then I query against both indices together, using a scripted metric aggregation as follows:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/expenses,currencylookup/_search?search_type=count" -d'
{
    "aggs": {
        "results": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "_agg[\"exp\"] = []; _agg[\"cur\"] = []",
                "map_script" : "if (doc[\"_type\"].value == \"inr\") { _agg.cur.add([doc[\"currency\"].value, doc[\"inr_per_unit\"].value]) } else { _agg.exp.add([doc[\"currency\"].value, doc[\"amount\"].value]) }",
                "reduce_script" : "exp=[]; cur=[]; for (item in _aggs) { exp += item.exp; cur += item.cur }; results=[]; for (c in cur) { for (e in exp) { if (e[0] == c[0]) { results.add(e[1]*c[1]) } } }; return results;"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

which yields the converted values:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 8,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "results": {
         "value": [
            5508.79985284,
            6189.662756,
            50,
            0.15055881000000002
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

To limit the results to only those in `usd`, we can use a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/expenses,currencylookup/_search?search_type=count" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "currency": "usd"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "converted_expenses": {
         "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg[\"exp\"] = []; _agg[\"cur\"] = []",
            "map_script": "if (doc[\"_type\"].value == \"inr\") { _agg.cur.add([doc[\"currency\"].value, doc[\"inr_per_unit\"].value]) } else { _agg.exp.add([doc[\"currency\"].value, doc[\"amount\"].value]) }",
            "reduce_script": "exp=[]; cur=[]; for (item in _aggs) { exp += item.exp; cur += item.cur }; results=[]; for (c in cur) { for (e in exp) { if (e[0] == c[0]) { results.add(e[1]*c[1]) } } }; return results;"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

yielding:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "converted_expenses": {
         "value": [
            5508.79985284,
            6189.662756
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I have my doubts that this approach is going to scale very well. Like I said, it probably isn't the best way to solve the problem. If it were me, I would probably find a way to do the conversions in application code rather than in Elasticsearch. But there you go.

Here is the code I used in working through this problem:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/6e7c8467ad7732c296448cec86e5c25e3c3c7326

(to use this code in the browser you will have to set `http.cors.enabled: true` in your elasticsearch instance; cross-origin access is turned off by default in v1.4.2)

Edit: There doesn't seem to be a way to further aggregate on the results using this technique, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Scripted metric aggregation seems like an option that gives some flexibility to process data. But I am also not in favor of using it extensively.

And if I do all pre-processing outside elasticsearch, then all correlations/computations will have to be predefined . I have just cited a tiny example here in my question, and the number of data sources I will have to correlate could be many more and with varied/complex structure. When all preprocessing is done outside elasticsearch, I will not be able to do dynamic processing of data by looking at some patterns on the fly.

Comment: Overall, I am not sure if there is any elegant and simple/cleaner way of correlating multiple data sources and then doing computations/aggregations on correlated data within elasticsearch framework. That would mean doing heavy-lifting related to data processing outside and limiting the correlation capability once data goes into elasticsearch.